# Text input allows for more than 3 characters

Tags: javascript

I have an input where the user can enter initials. The input has a max length of 3.

I have the following js

```
    personaliseShirt.plInitials = function () {
        console.log('pressed');
        var inputPL = $('.max-length_3');

        $(inputPL).on('keyup', function () {
            var max = 3;
            console.log(inputPL.val.length);
            if (inputPL.val.length > max) {
                inputPL.val = inputPL.value.substring(0, max);
            }
        })
    }
```

My issue is that the first input field seems to stop the user from entering more than 3 characters but if the user has multiple, then after the first input the rest allow for more than 3 :/

HTML for input field

```
<input onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" maxlength="3" type="text" class="form-control input-block-level defaultY? max-length_3" max="3" value="" placeholder="Enter Player Initials" name="player_2_9_6" id="player_2_9_6">
```

Any help or suggestions would be great

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are your other inputs?

Comment: all use this same input, there can be up to 10 of these on a page.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `inputPL` is a JQuery array with multiple elements in it. In your `keyup` handler, you check for the length of this array, which won't work. Use `this` instead:

```
personaliseShirt.plInitials = function () {
    console.log('pressed');
    var inputPL = $('.max-length_3');

    $(inputPL).on('keyup', function () {
        var max = 3;
        var $thisElem = $(this);
        console.log($thisElem.val.length);
        if ($thisElem.val.length > max) {
            $thisElem.val = $thisElem.value.substring(0, max);
        }
    })
}
```

Also please check, if your mix-up of `val` and `value` is intended, or if you need to use `val()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's working on firefox and chrome. You can use this function for repeated use.

```
$('input.testinput').on('keyup', function() {
    limitText(this, 3)
});

function limitText(field, maxChar){
    var ref = $(field),
        val = ref.val();
    if ( val.length >= maxChar ){
        ref.val(function() {
            console.log(val.substr(0, maxChar))
            return val.substr(0, maxChar);       
        });
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sovp7dL/)